# What is the reverse of (ArrayList).toString for a Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, encoding, tostring

I am using the `toString` method of `ArrayList` to store `ArrayList` data into a String.  My question is, how do I go the other way? Is there an existing method that will parse the data in the `String` instance back into an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Note that if the elements of the List are not String objects then the reverse action might be impossible to do because `theList.toString()` will call `toString()` on all elements and that might or might not be a reversable action (i.e. the String representation might not contain all information necessary to reproduce the original object).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is "No". There is no simple way to re-import an Object from a String, since certain type information is lost in the `toString()` serialization.

However, for specific formats, and specific (known) types, you should be able to write code to parse a String manually:

```
// Takes Strings like "[a, b, c]"
public List parse(String s) {
  List output = new ArrayList();
  String listString = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1); // chop off brackets
  for (String token : new StringTokenizer(listString, ",")) {
    output.add(token.trim());
  }
  return output;
}
```

Reconstituting objects from their **serialized** form is generally  called **deserialization**

Comment: In this case, I was using strings, so I guess parsing it myself is simple enough.  Thank you.

Comment: Of course, this would work only if the strings don't themselves contain the comma characters, which is the first point in my response.

Comment: Personally I would create a Codec class for this, so it is possible to parameterize the class (later on) and check for specific good/bad encodings.

Comment: What if my string in the arraylist contains ',' in it ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar question:

[Reverse (parse the output) of Arrays.toString(int[])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456367/reverse-parse-the-output-of-arrays-tostringint)

It depends on what you're storing in the ArrayList, and whether or not those objects are easily reconstructed from their String representations.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using some standard format with a library for it instead.

[JSON](http://json.org/java/) is probably the closest syntactically.

Alternatively some XML or serialization based solution could work too. It all depends on your needs of course.

Comment: The List.toString() format is pretty different from JSON. In fact it's a lot simple (and a lot less powerful). Using a JSON library is overkill (and probably just wrong).

Comment: Implementing own buggy parser is just wrong. Using tested library is much better, always.

Answer (score 0):

What does the ArrayList consist of? As others said, it may be impossible in certain cases, but quite possible and guaranteed to work *if*:

- each string representation of element of the array can be identified unambiguously (as it can be for example if the ArrayList consists of `Integer`s)
- there is a way to create an object of original type from its String representation. I find it most elegant to do this using a static method `fromString`

Of course, this mimics the whole (de)serialization framework.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons ftw.

```
Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(StringUtils.substringBetween("[1, 2, 3]", "[", "]"), ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> parseStringToList(String column) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    String listString = column.substring(1, column.length() - 1);
    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(listString,",");
    while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()){
      output.add(stringTokenizer.nextToken());
    }
    return output;
  }
```

In case the above gives a compilation error. (Can't use forEach on StringTokenizer)