# How can I convert a String back to a String[] if I used `Arrays.toString` to convert it like that in the first place?

Tags: java

I'm using a queue service that seems to only allow me to send a string as the message(sort of don't think thats right but haven't been able to prove otherwise), but I need 3 different data items to process my work(an int, double and int[]). So I take all three datatypes and convert them to a string using `Arrays.toString`.

My problem is once my worker processes get the message I need to convert them back. The worker sees this: `[0, 43.0, [0, 59, 16]]` but I'm not sure how to most efficiently convert it. The way I'm doing it right now is to remove the first and last characters and then doing a `String[] temp = queue_string.split(",");` to get it back as a list.

I'm fine if this way is the only way but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way? just like the  `Arrays.toString` is there something like a  `String.toArray`(this doesn't exist, I tried already :-)

Comment: duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456367/reverse-parse-the-output-of-arrays-tostringint). As mentioned your best bet would be to use StringUtils.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it'd be best to use a standard like JSON as the format for data transported between processes. Data can easily be marshaled from a string to native data types and back in Java.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

int[] sub = { 0, 59, 16 };
Object[] values = { 0, 43.0, sub };
String output = gson.toJson(values);       // => [0, 43.0,[0,59,16]]

Object[] deserialized = gson.fromJson(output, Object[].class);
for ( Object obj : deserialized ) {
    // => 0.0, 43.0, [0.0, 59.0, 16.0]
}
```

- [Google's gson library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [Original Java JSON library](http://www.json.org/java/)
- [More about JSON in Java](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+json)

Comment: The Gson lib Rocks, i use Array.toString(int[]) to store a string in my db and new Gson().fromJson(raw, int[].class); to convert it back. thanks!